# Google sheet array formula + Join + Filter

Tags: join, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

Does anyone know how I could expand the join+filter with arrayformula?
I need it to automatically expand instead of sliding the formulae into new rows.

Tried to search this problem but couldn't find a solution for myself.

[Copy to sheet itself](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b0x_gapgmts9GHModQViIL7IpGmLmCfmmrrDvd1MaQ0/edit?usp=sharing)

Problem in question highlighted in orange.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

use in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FILTER(
 {A2:A&"×", TEXT(B2:B, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss")&" ;", B2:B}, J2:J<>""), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3")),,
 9^9))), "×"), 2, 0), "^ |;$", )))
```

[image]