# Google sheet array formula with Filter & Join

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to build a table based on the following data:

| Ref | Product |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | ProdA |
| R2 | ProdC |
| R1 | ProdB |
| R3 | ProdA |
| R4 | ProdC |

And here the result I need:

| My Product | All Ref |
| --- | --- |
| ProdA | R1#R3 |
| ProdC | R2#R4 |

The particularity is that the 'My Product' column is computed elsewhere. So I need an arrayformula based on 'My Product' column to look in the first table to build the 'All Ref' column. You follow me?

I know that Arrayformula is not compatible with filter and join ... I expect a solution like this one [Google sheet array formula + Join + Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067714/google-sheet-array-formula-join-filter) but not sure to understand all steps and if really adapted to my case study.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

CREDIT: **player0** for the method shared to similar questions

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(substitute(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(QUERY({B2:B&"", A2:A&"#"}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"),,999^99)), "")), "#$", )," ",""))
```

[image]

**Step by step:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nabnub for this proposal, I think you're very close. The only issue is the column D in your result screenshot. This column is set up by anoter formula. I only need an arrayformula in Col E based on Refs given in Col D. Do you think this feasible without adding a new step ?

Comment: Then you can take only 2nd column from this formula... =index( solution formula,,2)

Comment: I managed to do it that way: Add 2 columns (F,G) in my sheet with the formula =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({C1:C&IF(LEN(C1:C),",",), D1:D&IF(LEN(C1:C),"|",)}, "SELECT MAX(Col2) WHERE Col1 != '' GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1"),,999^99)),",")),"\|$",))       and Adding another formula just after my list to search for: =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A1:A),F:G,2, FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the workaround hacks I implemented a simple [`joinMatching(matches, values, texts, [sep])`](https://github.com/iki/tricka-pro-prales/blob/main/api/sheet/joinMatching.js)  function in [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

In your case it would be just `=joinMatching(MyProductColumn, ProductColumn, RefColumn, "#")`.

Source:

````js
// Google Apps Script to join texts in a range where values in second range equal to the provided match value
// Solves the need for `arrayformula(join(',', filter()))`, which does not work in Google Sheets
// Instead you can pass a range of match values and get a range of joined texts back

const identity = data => data

const onRange = (data, fn, args, combine = identity) =>
  Array.isArray(data)
    ? combine(data.map(value => onRange(value, fn, args)))
    : fn(data, ...(args || []))

const _joinMatching = (match, values, texts, sep = '\n') => {
  const columns = texts[0]?.length
  if (!columns) return ''
  const row = i => Math.floor(i / columns)
  const col = i => i % columns
  const value = i => values[row(i)][col(i)]
  return (
    // JSON.stringify(match) +
    texts
      .flat()
      // .map((t, i) => `[${row(i)}:${col(i)}] ${t} (${JSON.stringify(value(i))})`)
      .filter((_, i) => value(i) === match)
      .join(sep)
  )
}

const joinMatching = (matches, values, texts, sep) =>
  onRange(matches, _joinMatching, [values, texts, sep])```
````